# Dropdownlist in UpdatePanel in UserControl is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, updatepanel, postback

I have this code inside a UserControl:

ControlloUtente.ascx

```
<td>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlE" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        </Triggers>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlE" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlE_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Text1" Value="1" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Text2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Text3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</td>
```

The UserControl is inside antoher UserControl:

ListaControlli.ascx

```
<%@ Register Src="~/BlaBla.ascx" TagName="BlaBla"
TagPrefix="UcBla" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/ControlloUtente.ascx" TagName="ControlloUtente"
TagPrefix="UcCon" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/BlaBla2.ascx" TagName="BlaBla2" 
TagPrefix="UcBla2" %>
```

That is in a page that already have an UpdatePanel:

Pagina.aspx

```
    <%@ Register Src="~/AltroUserControl.ascx" TagName="AUC" TagPrefix="ucAuc" %>
    <%@ Register Src="~/ListaControlli.ascx" TagName="Controlli" TagPrefix="uclControlli" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPagina" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
        <ContentTemplate>
            (...)
            <uclControlli:Controlli ID="ucControlli" runat="server" />
            (...)
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="ucAuc" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

But changing value of the dropdownlist I'm always having a full postback. There's something wrong?

Comment: Could you remove **Triggers** and **asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger** tags, and try again?

Comment: @Win Tried, but still no working.

Comment: how about setting your UpdatePanel `UpdateMode="Conditional"`?

Comment: @terbubbs Still having full postback.